# How can I use two versions of Flutter on the same device for different projects?

Tags: dart, flutter, sdk

I have a stable Flutter channel SDK located at *C:\flutter*. Which is set at the system environment variables to be the default path for Flutter.

And I'm using the path *C:\flutter* when creating new Flutter project in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) for our customers.

I also downloaded the Flutter master channel at *C:\flutter_master* and I need to use this Flutter SDK (master) for another project.

How can I correctly have two working Flutter versions on the same device for different projects without playing with the system environment variables each time?

Answer (score 57):

Firstly, you need to download all the Flutter SDKs you would want to be able to switch locally and create aliases for it. This allows you to use multiple versions of the SDK through the command line or the terminal, Just like you use any flutter command, And in case you want to use these different versions of your SDK in your IDE, you need to add the SDK paths to the settings of your IDE. Below you can find the steps to add the path to Visual Studio Code. The below answer will help you setup the different versions of SDK regardless of whether you are on Windows, Linux, or Mac.

#### Creating alias on Mac/Linux

This is how I have done it on an [M1 Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air_(Apple_silicon)#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon)),

I have different versions of Flutter SDKs downloaded in a `Documents` folder located at `$HOME/Documents`.

[image]

In order to access the appropriate version of Flutter through the terminal, we need to create aliases. Think of aliases as a shortcut to accessing the SDK through the terminal.

1. To create an alias you need to create `.bash_aliases` file inside your $HOME directory

   You can do this via a terminal by running

   ```
   nano ~/.bash_aliases
   ```

   Paste these aliases with the appropriate path in the file.

   ```
   alias flutterd='~/Documents/flutter_dev/bin/flutter'
   alias flutterm='~/Documents/flutter_master/bin/flutter'
   alias flutterb='~/Documents/flutter_beta/bin/flutter'
   ```

   Note that you can *name the aliases as you like*.

   I have used the name

   - `flutterd` to point to flutter_dev
   - `flutterm` to point to flutter_master
   - `flutterb` to point to flutter_beta

   That means when you type `flutterd` in the terminal then it will use the SDK located at `~/Documents/flutter_dev/bin/flutter` and respectively for rest of the aliases.

   (Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and enter to save and exit.)
2. And lastly, you need to add this in your shell file

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
   . ~/.bash_aliases
   fi
   ```

   which is basically the *rc* file

   `$HOME/.bashrc` if you are using [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29).

   `$HOME/.zshrc` file if you are using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (executable `zsh`)

   > if you are not sure then typing `echo $SHELL` in your Terminal tells you which shell you’re using.
   > This is the same file where you have added your Flutter SDK's path when you first installed it. And if the file doesn't exist you may create it.
3. Run `source $HOME/.<rc file>` to refresh the current terminal window.

   Now you can verify by typing your alias names in the terminal `flutterm`, `flutterd`, etc. and it will respond from the respective SDK.

   You can verify this by running `<alias name> doctor -v`.

   For example, to verify *flutterd* is pointing to *dev*, run `flutterd doctor -v`.

   Here is my output when I run the command:

   [image]

#### Creating an alias on Windows

On Windows, I have the Flutter SDKs stored in `C:/flutter_sdk`.

[image]

And then create an Alias folder and create batch files corresponding to each flutter SDK, where each batch file contains the path to a Flutter SDK.

[image]

For example, `flutterd.bat` contains the path to the `dev` SDK.

```
@echo off
C:\flutter_sdk\dev\bin\flutter %*
```

> Name your batch files wisely, because you will be using them from the command line. e.g  I have a batch file named as `flutterb.bat` to point to the beta channel, so to access the beta SDK I will use `flutterb` in the command line and not `flutter`.

And finally, we need to add the alias folder to the environment variable in order to make it accessible throughout Windows.

Go to Environment Variables* → *User Variables* → *Path* → <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>New</kbd>.

[image]

Now you can verify if everything works fine by opening command prompt and enter `flutterb doctor` and it should show the SDK pointing to beta

[image]

#### Adding multiple SDK versions to Visual Studio Code

Now to access the appropriate version of the SDK in Visual Studio Code you need to add these SDK paths in settings.

- In Visual Studio Code settings (*Code* → *Preferences* → *Settings*), search for *SDK path*
- Under Flutter SDK paths, add all the paths

  [image]
- Now when you open a Flutter project, you can choose your desired version by clicking on the Flutter version at the bottom

  [image]
- And it will prompt you to choose the SDK to use.

  [image]

Note that if you are changing versions from Visual Studio Code, you should also run `flutter pub get` from the right top icon in *[pubspec.yaml](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec)*, so that the source code updates as per the chosen SDK. You may confirm this by looking at the class definition of the source code.

Comment: Does it work on building iOS? I have trouble running different versions using xCode. I am not sure if there is way to tell xCode to use different sdk?

Comment: Good question! Yes, there is a way you can either `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` from vscode and flutter will set the currently selected path at `ios/Flutter/generated.xcConfig` or you can manually set the SDK path in that file.

Comment: I tried above steps it gives me error `\Documents\flutter_sdk\flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Did I miss something?

Comment: @Nicks I would recommend checking the above answer again, probably you have made some mistake when adding path to batch files and also ensure you have added the alias path in environment variables and try the flutter command in new instance of cmd

Comment: Be careful if you install npm globally. If you `source ~/.zshrc `, then don't forget to `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` . Or else you can't find npm included in your path

Comment: One more step that was required : 
After the above steps, In the bottom of VS code, there is a '{}' icon, click on it and restart Dart Language Server to see the above changes.

This is for people who have different version of Dart as well being used ( not only Flutter)

Comment: So when I do all these steps I am getting a warning that `The flutter binary is not on your path. Consider adding/Users/lakshay/Developer/flutter/bin to your path`. should I just continue on & ignore the warning or have I missed something?
I am on the M1 platform.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that your bash scripts now have things like "flutterd", so they're not likely to work on other people's machines.  I think PATH variables are simpler and don't create the "flutterd" issue.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 19):

The Flutter SDK can be specified per workspace if you use Visual Studio Code. You need to:

1. Clone the Flutter repository to a new folder:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/flutter_dev
   cd ~/flutter_dev
   git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git .
   ```
2. Create `.vscode/settings.json` with the following content:

   ```json
   {
     "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/youruser/flutter_dev"
   }
   ```
3. Restart Visual Studio Code and you're good to go.

See more information in *[Dart Code - Quickly Switching Between SDK Versions](https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-sdk-versions/)*.

Comment: The linked docs for Dart Code plugin are excellent, especially the note the doc includes on using `git worktree` to have multiple Flutter channels installed using a single local Flutter SDk install (git repo).

Comment: "settings": {
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/youruser/flutter_dev"
}                where I have to write this line , in which file , please more explanation

Comment: @Sana'aAl-ahdal see this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I fixed it by doing  and creating Alias , like the one described here 
  https://medium.com/@sarbagyastha/using-two-or-more-different-versions-of-flutter-in-single-machine-484293c2a7ff

Comment: A small note: If you git clone the flutter repo inside a folder called 'flutter_dev', then you  need to reference the flutter folder inside the flutter_dev folder. E.g. "/Users/youruser/flutter_dev/flutter"

Comment: In the article it said git worktree add ../flutter-master origin/master, so I can quickly switch between flutter/dart sdk versions. But, in the status bar it doesn’t clickable, just show existing version (2.2.3). Any suggest?

Comment: @bandungeuy the status bar button won't be clickable. It's not a toggle, it's just a text indicating the current Flutter version that VSCode is using. You need to update the version manually in `settings.json` and restart VSCode.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev that what I’m asking related to above article. Anyway, finally I did it, the status bar now clickable, so if I want to switch flutter version, just click it and select other version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196386/vscode-quickly-switch-between-flutter-versions

Comment: @bandungeuy thanks a lot, I didn't know it was possible! My mistake.

Comment: In my vs code, It has double backward slashes:  `{"dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\src\\3.10.0"}`

Answer (score 15):

Now you can use “FVM”, and it's Flutter Version Management, A simple CLI to manage Flutter SDK versions per project.

1 you can use it by this command

```
pub global activate fvm
```

2 after that you can install any versions you want like

```
fvm install stable

fvm install 'flutter version'
```

it will be installed at

```
 /Users/'username'/fvm/versions/
```

3 to switch versions:

```
fvm use 'flutter version'
```

for more info, visit [FVM.app](https://fvm.app)

Comment: I think is good idea add 'flutter' before pub n_n 
flutter pub global activate fmv

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Android Studio, you can set difference version of Flutter for each project from menu *File* → *Setting* → *Languages & Frameworks* → *Flutter*:

[image]

And to run Flutter/Dart from the command line for multiple Flutter versions, you can follow the article *[Using two or more different versions of Flutter on a single machine](https://medium.com/@sarbagyastha/using-two-or-more-different-versions-of-flutter-in-single-machine-484293c2a7ff)*.

Comment: It would be best to check for [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) before posting a link to a [Medium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_(website)) article. Medium is infested with ***blatant*** plagiarism (wholesale copying of blog posts from other Medium posts or from elsewhere)

Answer (score 8):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24236#issuecomment-437772228) in Flutter's repository, *iqbalmineraltown* has the answer:

> You might want to download multiple version as you need, because each Flutter SDK version is tightly coupled with specific Dart SDK.

You set the Flutter version for each project, and *iqbalmineraltown* highlights a way if you're using Visual Studio Code:

> If you're using VSCode [sic], you can download multiple version of flutter SDK into different path and quickly switch between them using [Dart&Flutter Plugin](https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-sdk-versions/)
> You can set default SDK for each project by providing default SDK path for each workspace. So when you open a project, VSCode [sic] will use the version you specified for that project.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using this tutorial over [here](https://medium.com/@sarbagyastha/using-two-or-more-different-versions-of-flutter-in-single-machine-484293c2a7ff). I made some changes for Mac:

**For Unix/Mac-based OS users**

Edit file *[$HOME/.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* (for me it was file *[$HOME/.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)* on Mac) file and add this line (if it doesn’t exist).

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

2. Create and edit file *[$HOME/.bash_aliases](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/%7E/.bash_aliases)* and add aliases as you want.

```
alias flutter2='~/development/sdks/flutter2/bin/flutter'
alias flutter='~/development/sdks/flutter/bin/flutter'
```

Using the same technique, I've kept the `flutter2` setup separate from `flutter1`. Because in some projects I need two and in older projects the version 1.

Now open the specific project in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) and open command palette (on Mac, the command was <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) and search for `flutter sdk`.

[image]

Now choose **Auto-Detect**, which will create a new file under root of your project's *[.vscode/settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* file.

[image]

Open this file and place the path of Flutter version you want to use like below:

```
{
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/imran/flutter2"
}
```

Do remember to run `flutter2 --doctor`, to resolve any issues.

While setting up `flutter2`, I encountered an issue and fix for that is here: *[I am getting error "cmdline-tools component is missing" after installing Flutter and Android Studio... I added the Android SDK. How can I solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-this-errors-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-f)*.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply rename the folder without playing with the system environment variables each time.

1. Suppose you downloaded Flutter 2.0.5 under flutter folder & 2.2.2 under flutter_2.2.2 folder, added flutter to environment path as C:\src\flutter.
2. Whenever you want 2.2.2 version rename flutter_2.2.2 to flutter & flutter to flutter_2.0.5.
   [image]

Comment: This was the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FVM](https://fvm.app) to manage versions of Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of the answers so far are adequate.  Operating systems created the PATH variable to solve just this problem.  The problem with creating aliases, such as "flutterd" is that flutterd only works on your machine.

Here's a cleaner way to do things.

1. Create a script called "setup-env.sh" in your project root directory:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   export PATH=/path/to/your/flutter/version:$PATH
   ```
2. Anytime you work on this project, just do "source ./setup-env.sh" and you will be pointing to the correct flutter version.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer these days is [Puro](https://puro.dev).  I've stopped using FVM entirely, and switched over to Puro.  See the homepage for how it is better in many ways than FVM or by hand.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Just a happy user.

Answer (score 0):

Having several versions of SDKs installed and adjusting project-specific IDE SDK settings seem reasonable, but I prefer commandline tools and when you call the `flutter` command, it always calls the one on the path. So I can't use this solution.

The alias solution [mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68047743) is preferable for me, but when used it, I often forgot to call with alias (such as `flutterb`), leading to calling the wrong version of Flutter. After accidentally doing this, I usually need to do a `flutter clean` as well.

What I use, inspired by alias solution, is that I added a `flutter.bat` file in the root folder of the project. It contains the following lines:

```
@echo off
C:\SDK\flutter1\bin\flutter %*
```

As you may guess, this location belongs to the specific Flutter installation for using with this project. It is not the version on the path, but since I call all `flutter` commands from the root folder of the project, my terminal session sees this Flutter first and it uses this version, rather than the global one on the path.  You can confirm this by calling [`flutter doctor`](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#run-flutter-doctor) for the first time.

- Note that this is for using *constant* versions for each project, rather than trying several versions on the same project. For that kind of use case, you can combine this with the alias solution.
- Also note that this is a *Windows* solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) to do that:

Download multiple Flutter versions from this Flutter official site [flutter_archives](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows).

Then set up those ZIP files like this:

[image: Flutter paths]

Open Visual Studio Code and go to settings.
Change settings like this (use double slashes "\")

[image]

Now you can easily switch between Flutter SDKs by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and searching for Flutter SDKs.

[image]

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably? What version and edition was it tested on? [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77051687/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

First the download the required flutter SDK.

[image]

If you are using Android Studio, you can change the Flutter version by navigating to Android Studio -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Flutter. After changing the version, apply the settings and check the bottom section to confirm the current version.

For double confirmation, you can also go to Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Doctor, where you can see the Flutter version used by the project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put all the versions folders in the Documents folder. (as shown below:)

[image]

1. Open Terminal.
2. Type: nano ~/.bash_aliases
3. Paste the aliases with the appropriate path in the file:

   ```
   alias flutter_sn='~/Documents/flutter_3.10.5/flutter/bin/flutter'
   alias flutter_rg='~/Documents/flutter_3.13.7/flutter/bin/flutter'
   ```
4. Hit “Ctrl+X” & “Yes” for saving.
5. Hit Enter.
6. Quit Terminal & Reopen it.
7. Type: vim ~/.zshrc & press “i” to edit.
8. And Paste the below:

```
export PATH=”$PATH:/Users/yourUserName/Documents/flutter_3.13.9/flutter/bin”
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then 
. ~/.bash_aliases 
fi
```

9. Press “esc” & enter the command “:wq!”
10. Again quit terminal and reopen it.
11. Run this command:  doctor -v (example: flutter_rg doctor -v)
12. Now Go to VS Code => Code => Settings => SDK => Flutter SDK Paths => Add all the paths:
    example:

```
“/Users/yourUserName/Documents/flutter_3.10.5”
```

13. Now at the bottom in vscode, we can change and switch the version of flutters according to the project need.[image]