# Can we have multiple Flutter SDKs in one machine?

Tags: flutter, sdk, channel, flutter-channel

Can I have multiple flutter SDK versions installed on my machine?

As we know on stable version, flutter web did not release yet. can i have 2 different channels of flutter sdk on my machine one represents flutter stable channel and other represent flutter master channel.

Kindly let me know how to do this because i already have 2 SDK's of flutter and both are in C drive and when i upgrade one SDK, it automatically upgrade other SDK as well. And i do not want it, i want them to be on separate channels.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24236

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can perform this, the latest and most common one is using the [Flutter Version Manager](https://fvm.app/).

> A simple CLI to manage Flutter SDK versions.

But if you want to manually set up your machine, you can explore [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783494/how-can-i-use-two-versions-of-flutter-on-the-same-device-for-different-projects).

See also the following blogs for more info:

- [Multiple Flutter Versions On A Single Machine](https://medium.com/@harisatiq15/multiple-flutter-versions-on-a-single-machine-60f7b581cdb7)
- [Using two or more different versions of Flutter on single machine](https://medium.com/@sarbagyastha/using-two-or-more-different-versions-of-flutter-in-single-machine-484293c2a7ff)