# I am getting error "cmdline-tools component is missing" after installing Flutter and Android Studio... I added the Android SDK. How can I solve them?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-doctor

Android toolchain - I develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3):

```
X cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
```

Comment: Could you share the ```flutter doctor``` summary?

Answer (score 1139, accepted):

The solution for me was opening Android Studio and going to *SDK Manager*, switch to the *SDK Tools* tab and check *Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)*.

[image]

Don't forget to add to your PATH the tools and platform-tools folder that are inside your SDK.

Comment: @Felipe-carvalho how do i ```Don't forget to add to your PATH the tools and platform-tools folder that are inside your Sdk``` ?

Comment: Depends on your operating system.
This tutorial (https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7) provides a way of adding folders to your PATH environment variable on the most used OSs.

Look for your Android SDK folder, and you'll find the "tools" and "platform-tools" folder.

Comment: It only worked for me after I added a bunch of folders to my Ubuntu installation ~/.profile file: `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/build-tools/32.1.0-rc1/
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/Sdk/emulator/bin64/`

Comment: On Mac OS : Monterey, after selecting and applying : "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)." The SDK Component Installer installs the tools  without the requirements to add PATH

Comment: Bro , flutter should put the link to your answer in their flutter doctor

Comment: Flutter doctor cmd prompting to install visual studio to me in windows environment. but, I just want to develop for android. should I need to install a visual studio, I hope flutter should work without it.

Comment: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin also you can check on Appearance & Behavior > System Settins > Android SDK on the "Android SDK Location" input box, or even Edit that value ;)

Comment: @Katu you most definitely do NOT have to add those paths and I would strongly advise you not to. All that has to be set is your ANDROID_HOME and ensure the components are installed by the sdk manager/sdk tools.

Comment: @RichieHH without that, it didn't work for me. Why do you strongly advice not to do that? What is the downside to adding folders to the path?

Comment: I don't have a `tools` folder inside the `sdk` directory. I only have `platform-tools`, `build-tools`, `cmdline-tools` (after installing these command line tools), `emulator`, `licenses`, `patcher`, and `platforms`. I'm running macOS Ventura.

Comment: I love you ... I was about to loose my mind there

Comment: To access the SDK manager, open Android Studio and any random project, then from the top menu, go to Tools->SDK Manager

Comment: Thank you. I want Unity to use all the SDK installations that Android Studio has installed so I don't waste dozens of gigs of hard drive space with a second fricking copy of everything. Naturally Unity docs do not state you need this particular package, only a different one (the "Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)" package).

Answer (score 211):

Since my Android Studio starting screen looks different from the answers above, I want to share my solution:

[image: An image of the 'Welcome to Android Studio' screen. An arrow highlights the "More Actions" dropdown menu on the bottom of this screen, and a second arrow highlights the "SDK Manager" option within the dropdown menu.]

- Open Android Studio and click on '*more actions*' on the welcome screen.
- Click on '*SDK Manager*'

  [image: An image of the "Preferences" window within Android Studio. "Android SDK" is selected on the left, then on this settings page, "SK Tools is selected from a top-bar menu. The item called "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" is checked, and changes are applied.]
- In the 'Preferences' window go to the '*SDK Tools*' tab
- Select the '*Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)*' checkbox.
- Click on <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

Comment: This solved the issue. Worth mentioning that last step is: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: This is the correct solution for Mac users

Comment: ur screen is because u did not have any project created

Answer (score 141):

Android SDK Manager screenshot on Windows

[image]

Please see the attached screenshot for installing tools from SDK Manager.

Answer (score 125):

1. Open SDK Manager from your Android Studio.
2. You can find SDK manager from the menubar → *Tools* → *SDK Manager* or use the icon. As in the picture.

   [image]
3. *SDK Tools* tab
4. Check *Android SDK Command Line Tools* as in the picture
5. <kbd>Apply</kbd>

   [image]
6. Then *again run* `flutter doctor` in your terminal.

Answer (score 62):

My solution process is as follows:

1. `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
       at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
       at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
       at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
       ... 5 more
   ```
2. Install Android SDK Command-line Tools in Android Studio:

   *Preferences* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *Android SDK* → *SDK Tools* → *Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)*
3. `flutter doctor`

   ```
   Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
   [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
   [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
   [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
   [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
   [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
   [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
   [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
   [✓] Connected device (2 available)

   • No issues found!
   ```

Comment: I like these steps! Let me know we are same errors, then can keep with the solution!

Comment: For me just step 2 resolved the Issue.

Comment: Beyond these operations I had to execute this command on the 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' to accept all Android lincenses

Comment: Step 2 can also be found by following instructions posted by Md. Shahariar Hossen below.

Comment: Flutter devs should really take a page from your solution sir. This worked!

Answer (score 49):

#### For Windows users

If you still see the same error even after your build tools, tools are installed and added to the `user/system` path variable, and maybe your `sdkmanager` location is really not found

- **Just type in**

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\{Your_User_Name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" # (Default SDK location)
```

- Add the path inside `""` to where your Android SDK folder is located
- Then you can run the licenses to verify any license which is not approved.

This worked for me.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Because of storage shortage, I had to move my sdk folder to D drive, that's why even after intalling the tools and setting the path the issue persisted! Your solution saved me a lot of time!

Comment: thank you, for my case i installed sdk in D:\sdk, i just need to run command above with my sdk path and it's working now.

Comment: That was the missing step for my chromeos / debian install.  Thank you

Answer (score 30):

Your Android SDK version requires an update.

Open Android Studio → click *Android Studio* on the top bar → *Preferences* → *Appearance & behavior* (click to open the dropdown) → *System Settings* (click to open the dropdown) → *Android SDK* → *SDK Tools* (tab).

Check *Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)* → *Apply* → click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Once the update has finished, run `flutter doctor`.

[Screenshot of the Appearance & Behavior menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2RlW.png)

Answer (score 26):

If what `flutter doctor` said was something like:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/<admin>/Library/Android/sdk
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
```

The `path/to/sdkmanager` for me was:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

So what solved the whole thing for me was running:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

Comment: What worked for me was running: flutter config --android-studio-dir="" and

flutter config --android-sdk=""

Comment: Clearing these values finally resolved the issue for me, after trying a plethora of solutions. Thanks !

Answer (score 25):

For macOS, I ran this command;

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin
./sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

Then when I ran the `flutter doctor` command again, it confirmed that the problem was solved.

Comment: I don't have the `tools` folder inside `~/Library/Android/sdk/`

Answer (score 16):

[image]

**Easiest solution:**

- Open Android Studio and click settings in the upper left corner of Android studio.
- Search for "SDK tools" in the search box.
- From the SDK tools just check the *Android SDK Platform Tools*.
- Run `flutter doctor` to verify. You can also restart Android Studio if you want. 
  I hope the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 15):

**For macOS users:**

```
flutter config --android-sdk "/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/Library/Android/sdk"
```

Then

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Type "y" for all stops.

Comment: At last, something solved it for me!

Answer (score 11):

If you have already downloaded cmdline-tools and the Android SDK, make sure Flutter isn't looking in the wrong directory with:

```
flutter config --android-sdk=""
```

Comment: Is "cmdline-tools" literal or do you mean "[command line](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/command_line#Noun) tools"?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients). We will probably never know.

Comment: cmdline-tools is literal, it's the name of the component, it refers to specific command line tools for flutter named cmdline-tools.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem on Windows 10 with the following actions:

1. Run the following command in a Windows command prompt or Flutter console:

   ```
   flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\'your computer name' AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
   ```

   (you may need to find and enter your own SDK path)

   The Android SDK location could be found in the Android Studio application* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *Android SDK*
2. Open your Android Studio, and then → *File* → *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *Android SDK* → *SDK Tools* → download Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a Mac user, just open your terminal and paste:

```
cd Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin./sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

And hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This command will install the latest version of *cmdline-tools*.

Then, run `flutter doctor`, and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 5):

For Linux ([Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29))

Just copy this command in your terminal and change 'your user name' with your user name without spaces:

```
/home/your user name/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

Answer (score 5):

I installed the Android SDK platform tool from Android Studio. This helped me to resolve this error.

[Error before installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX68i.png)

[Installed platform tool from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG592.png)

[After installation of Platform tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9L5.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when answering a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you provide the first and the last image as ***text*** instead, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac Monterey after following the default install process.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install *Android SDK Command-line Tools*.
To do that, invoke the menu command *File* → *Settings* → *Android SDK* and download the latest.

You must choose *Android SDK* on the left side of the *Settings* window. It’s under *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings*.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows I did two things to resolve it.

1. Launched Android Studio > More Actions > SDK Manager>SDK Tools and ticked and applied `Android SKD Command line tools`
2. Entered `flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` into the command line. The path came from the top of the screen in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

**For macOS users**

If you already have Android Studio installed, simply run:

```
flutter config --android-sdk "/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk" & flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for Windows:
If you are still facing the issue even after installing the "Android SDK Command-line Tools(latest)" thru Android Studio -> Settings->Appearance & Behavior -> Systems Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools,  You need to configure the flutter for Android SDK Path (Not the environment variable path).

Android SDK Will be installed under Program files e.g. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk).  If not this location, find out the location where it is installed and go to the bin folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\cmdline-tools\7.0\bin) and run

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk"
```

After this run flutter doctor, now this issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Android SDK Command-line Tools:

- For the updated version of Android Studio, the **Setting** is here:

```
Settings > Languages & Framework > Android SDK > SDK Tools (TAB)
```

[image: Android SDK Command-line Tools]

- **For older version:**

```
Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools (TAB)
```

[image: Android SDK Command-line Tools]

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the latest cmd-line tools from Android Studio, but it still gives the error, then you should do the following.

If you have installed the Android SDK to a custom directory, then you need to copy the path of your SDK folder. Then you have to go to the edit environment variable, click <kbd>New</kbd> give
a variable name: **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**. And a variable value: **path of your SDK folder**.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

In the older version of Flutter, this error came with the solution (creating ANDROID_SDK_ROOT), but in the new versions it does not show that.

Answer (score 1):

For me, running this command worked perfectly:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/your/sdk
```

Comment: On what system, incl. edition and version information (both for the environment, like the operating system, and for Flutter)?

Comment: At that time, I was using - MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) with macOS BigSur (11.7.9). Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 11.7.9 20G1426 darwin-x64, locale: en-US). As it was almost one year ago, now using newest m2 macbook, so far, no such problem.

Answer (score 1):

Goto:

1. Tool->SDK Manager and Apply SDK command line toolkit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I executed the below command to fix the issue on [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh):

```
/Users/<user username>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```