# "cmdline-tools component missing" error in flutter using VSCode

Tags: flutter

While installing flutter I am getting this error:

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
```

And I saw many solutions but they all use Android Studio, while I am using VSCode.

Comment: Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-this-errors-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-f Possible duplictate of this.

Comment: No its not same, its about Android Studio and so easy to locate in it. I am using VSCode so I am not able to solve it.

Comment: You can install manually from this link depend on the system you are using. 
 https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools   and 
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-setup-android-sdk-without-android-studio-6d60d0f2812a

Comment: Yes thank you, it worked. We need to download the command line tools separately and then place it in our ```\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk``` directory.

Answer (score 2):

For my case Installing Command-line Tools form sdk manager solved the problem.

Steps to install from sdkmanager:

1. Open sdk manager in Android Studio
2. Select `SDK Tools` tab
3. Select `Android SDK Command-line Tools` and then apply

[image: Steps]

You can download [command-line tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) manually and place it on sdk folder.
That also should work.