# Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I was following a tutorial to install an android emulator, without android studio, and I was told to run the command- `flutter doctor`. Upon running this, I got this error-

```
X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
```

So I tried running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, and I got this error-

```
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to
resolve this.
```

This is my `ANDROID_HOME` directory-

[image]

And Inside `platforms`, I have `android-32` installed.

I saw some fixes for this, but those were all with android studio. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're using the command line tool without android studio been installed todevelop mobile app here's a way around this issue I was able to resolve it.

[image]

First check if there are packages to be updated

```
sdkmanager --list
```

if there are then run the command below ensure you've good internet connection and power

```
sdkmanager --update
```

Next run

```
sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

Next run the command below and the error will not be there again.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses

flutter doctor
```

and you're good to go!!!
[image]

Comment: Ensure the enviroment variables are properly configured!

Comment: This solution works without Android Studio

Comment: This worked for me. I am installing flutter and the sdk without android studio. And this got my last tick when running flutter doctor. Thanks!

Comment: superb! this solution worked in my case

Comment: I was stuck on this for a long time, this fixed it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 44):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Preferences
3. Appearances tab on the left
4. System Settings
5. Android SDK[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moruL.png)
6. Click Show Package details
7. [Toggle SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi12D.png)
8. Apply and restart Android Studio
9. Run flutter doctor

Comment: This worked well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

If you are using Android Studio:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Goto `File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK` (Screenshot attached below)

[image: screenshot]
3. Update/Install `Android Studio Command-line Tools`.
4. Click apply and restart android studio.

Comment: Alternative for step 2: go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** then go to **SDK Tools** tab

Comment: This is now found in `File -> Languages & Frameworks -> Android SDK`

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the Android Studio. Then click on the `New Options`. There you can see a dropdown to navigate into `SDK manager`.
2. In the system settings open the `Android SDK`, then open the `SDK Tool Kit` options. Then check the `Android SDK command-line Tools(latest)`
3. Restart the Android Studio and run the command

   ```
   flutter doctor --android-licenses
   ```

Answer (score 6):

When you download the Android SDK command line tools from https://developer.android.com/studio#span-idcommand-toolsa-namecmdline-toolsacommand-line-tools-onlyspan, your folder structure will look something like this:

```
AndroidSDK/
    cmdline-tools/
        bin/
        lib/
        NOTICE.txt
        source.properties
```

It needs to be moved to

```
AndroidSDK/
    cmdline-tools/
        **latest/**
            bin/
            lib/
            NOTICE.txt
            source.properties
```

You already have the sdkmanager/cmdline-tools - you've already used it to download the platform tools etc. You just need to have it in the correct folder.

Once it's in the correct spot, your licenses message should change from:

```
X Android license status unknown.
```

when you run `flutter doctor`, to:

```
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

(I had already accepted a license when installing the platform tools)

Comment: Thank you, @divillysausages! Wow, that was confusing. Out of dozens of posts (mostly outdated), only your 0-upvote gem on Stack Overflow has the actual answer. 
The zip extracts to the folder "cmdline-tools", so after renaming it to "latest" and putting it inside another "cmdline-tools" within the sdk, sdkmanager is working!

Comment: This Soultion works perfect in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Open Android Studio,
Tools Menu, SDK Manager.
In the window that comes up there are inner panels, choose SDK Tools panel.
Tick Android SDK Command-line Tools.
Choose Apply button near the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 4):

juste install "Android SDK Command-line Tools" on android studio
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7EMn.png)
and than run again "flutter doctor --android-licenses"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DezoK.png)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to install [cmdLine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter/70125256#70125256)

please run **flutter doctor** and share cmd results to help better