# In Android Studio cmdline-tools component is missing

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

When run flutter doctor, the error { cmdline-tools component is missing }
even that I installed cmdline-tools as shown:

[image]

I also run c:/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" that output show is completed as bellow,

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting error "cmdline-tools component is missing" after installing Flutter and Android Studio... I added the Android SDK. How can I solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was needing to restart the PC