# flutter doctor - How to resolve Android sdkmanager cmdline-tools component is missing?

Tags: android, flutter, macos

Am trying to install/setup `flutter_macos_2.10.2-stable` on macOS Monterey 12.1.

Java version:

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

Output:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home`

Have `Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1` installed (along with the `flutter-dev 64.1.2` plug-in, also installed) inside Android Studio.

---

Inside `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/pnwlover/Library/Android/sdk";

export FLUTTER_HOME="/Users/pnwlover/DevTools/flutter/flutter_macos_2.10.2-stable";

PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:$FLUTTER_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin";
```

Now, when I run `flutter doctor -v`:

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at /Users/pnwlover/DevTools/flutter/flutter_macos_2.10.2-stable
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (3 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/pnwlover/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.102

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

When trying to do this:

`sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

Receive the following warning:

```
Warning: Unknown argument --install
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file <file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]

In its first form, installs, or uninstalls, or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.

    --uninstall: uninstalled listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

In its second form (with --update), all installed packages are
    updated to the latest version.

In its third form, all installed and available packages are printed
    out.

In its fourth form (with --licenses), show and offer the option to
     accept licenses for all available packages that have not already been
     accepted.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK 
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

What steps am I missing?

How can I install Android's sdkmanager's `cmdline-tools;latest`?

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting error "cmdline-tools component is missing" after installing Flutter and Android Studio... I added the Android SDK. How can I solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

so simple just open android studio and goto settings and search for SDK and the in the Android SDK tab at right side second than open and you will see cmd line tool tick the box the apply button then flutter doctor with new terminal will show just one error and for solving that use this command keep agree with license and press y and enter
this command after solving the first problem will work

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

[image]
[image]