# Flutter shows some errors

Tags: flutter

I am trying to connect my flutter app to my phone but it doesn't work...
I wrote `flutter doctor` in the terminal and it shows me some errors:

```
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
```

I am using VS code (if it's matters).
What is the path to SDK manager?
Why is it said to me that "Visual Studio not installed" if that wrote in the VS code terminal?

---

Thanks all!

Comment: VSCode is not Visual Studio, in case that was what was confusing you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting error "cmdline-tools component is missing" after installing Flutter and Android Studio... I added the Android SDK. How can I solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio can work no problem, **first you need to install Android Studio**, open Android Studio, open **SDK Manager**, install Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1 from SDK Tools, then open CMD(command prompt) run **flutter doctor --android-licenses** , prass enter y enter y enter..., then write **flutter doctor** and see run problem solve . Thank You.

[image]