# I'm getting the error 'cmdline-tools component is missing" and "Android license status unknown" , when i run the command flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

--------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx---------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx------------

I'm getting the above error on my windows 10 laptop. Can someone help me.

Comment: check a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter) asked.

Comment: Thank you @Unimke for the suggestion. The issue is solved now. Sorry for replying late got held up by exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using the following steps.

1. Updating the SDK in the Android Studio.
2. Updating the SDK tools in the Android Studio.
3. Downloading the Android SDK Command line Tools.

I followed this article : `https://flutter-developer.medium.com/flutter-flutter-doctor-results-with-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-f6371a9c6e97`