# Flutter - cmdline-tools component is missing

Tags: android, flutter, macos, android-studio

While running `flutter doctor` I am receiving this error:

> ```
> ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
>   Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
>   See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
> ✗ Android license status unknown.
>   Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
>   See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
>   more details.
> ```

I have tried to install `cmdline-tools` on SDK Manager but it did not help. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I believe this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter) covers your use case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running this command worked for me:

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/your/sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case by using Ubuntu, I solve it by the following step.

1. Set Flutter Android SDK path (run in terminal)

```bash
flutter config --android-sdk ~/Android/Sdk
```

2. Open Android Studio
3. Then open **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **Android SDK** -> **SDK Tools**
4. Check mark package with name "**Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)**"
5. Click Apply, then package downloading

After the download is complete, run again "f**lutter doctor**"