# Installing flutter: cant find path to sdk-manager

Tags: flutter, installation

I'm trying to install flutter, but its not working. Flutter doctor gives me the following:

[image]

now I can't find the path to my sdkmanager. I'm working on Windows. I tried to do this:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`

But that didn't worked out.

Also I can't find anything helpfull for that in the following folder.

[image]

Can someone tell me what to do here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome on your new journey to flutter development!

I had similar issue with the cmdline-tools component missing during installation process. However, following the answers given below for the stackoverflow question solved my issue.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)

[Answer given here is more specific to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036049/16413603)

If you still see the same error after installing `Android SDK command-line tools`  from Android Studio try running the following command in `command prompt`:

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users\<Replace_with_your_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
```

To solve the `Android license status unknown` just run the mentioned command:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And tap `y` thrice to accept the terms.

To solve `Visual studio not installed` just follow the documentation till step 4 (others are totally optional) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170 and install the free community edition.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Wow man thank you so much for your helpful and very kind response. That really helped.