# can't run flutter project on chrome

Tags: flutter

I created a sample flutter project and I want to see the result in chrome.

when I run `main.dart` on chrome I get a white blank page as result!

here is my `flutter doctor`:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-56- 
generic,locale en_US.UTF-8)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    cmdline-tools component is missing
    Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
    See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more 
    details.
Chrome - develop for the web
Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    clang++ is required for Linux development.
    It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt 
    install clang), or can be downloaded from 
    https://releases.llvm.org/
CMake is required for Linux development.
    It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt 
    install cmake), or can be downloaded from 
    https://cmake.org/download/
ninja is required for Linux development.
    It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt 
    install ninja-build), or can be downloaded from 
    https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
pkg-config is required for Linux development.
    It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt 
    install pkg-config), or can be downloaded from 
    https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/
Android Studio
    android-studio-dir = 
    /home/mbunderline76/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA- 
    U/ch-0
Unable to find bundled Java version.
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3)
Connected device (2 available)
HTTP Host Availability
Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

[image]

any idea what is going on?
by the way i'm using Intellij Idea Ultimate

Comment: Post the error code as text.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour i did it

Comment: did you run it as `flutter -v -d chrome run`? if so, what's the log output?

Comment: @pskink i get this error in chrome :
`js_util_patch.dart:105          GET https://unpkg.com/canvaskit-wasm@0.35.0/bin/canvaskit.js net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED`

Comment: @MohammadBaqer does it show anything in the debug console when you run it and get a blank screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix these issues first.

[Flutter command Line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236007/i-am-getting-error-cmdline-tools-component-is-missing-after-installing-flutter)

[Flutter Java Bundled Link](https://%20stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter)

then again run `flutter doctor` to make sure these errors are gone.

then run `flutter -v -d chrome run` Or Pick " Chrome Web " in your Vscode or AndroidStudio.

Hope this works, Enjoy.