# flutter doctor shows errors, that I don't seem to able to fix. Problems: System32, Android toolchain, Windows 10 sdk

Tags: flutter, dart, system32

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZaCJ.jpg)

I changed the variables in various ways, restarted this and that and I just cannot fix the issue, so what am I missing here?

The path variable always worked and now that I have deleted Visual Studio and Windows 10 SDK and re-downloaded it, everything seems to run out of control.

Here is the output of my 3 problems:

```
[  +33 ms] [☠] Flutter (the doctor check crashed)
[   +1 ms]     X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
                 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
[        ]     X Exception: Cannot find the executable for `where`. This can happen if the System32 folder (e.g. C:\Windows\System32 ) is removed from the PATH environmentvariable.
                 Ensure that this is present and then try again after restarting the terminal and/or IDE.
```

```
[  +28 ms] [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[        ]     • Android SDK at C:\Users\Tina\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
[        ]     X cmdline-tools component is missing
[        ]       Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
[        ]       See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
[        ]     X Android license status unknown.
[        ]       Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
[        ]       See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
```

```
[   +1 ms] [!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.5)
[        ]     • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
[        ]     • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.8.34511.84
[        ]     ! Unable to locate a Windows 10 SDK. If building fails, install the Windows 10 SDK in Visual Studio.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open SDK manager in Android studio and check Android SDK Command-line Tools

[image]

And for Android licenses run this command in your terminal.

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

[Answer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492909/19807154)

Comment: solved one problem! Thanks! :)

Comment: use \bin for second error add this in your path like : yourUsername\Flutter\sdk\flutter\bin

Comment: i did that already, but it still shows the same error

should i add it as a system variable or a user variable? or should both cases end up doing the same. because i tried both and both don't work

Comment: i don't have enough knowledge for windows but did you re-started your pc after making changes.?

Comment: yes I have, you can find my solution answer in the answers, it was just some path mistakes that I have made, probably because I changed them one too many times 

it's solved now

Answer (score 0):

SOVLED!

I made 2 mistakes:

- my flutter\bin path was wrong, I have mistaken it with another path
- In my System Variables --> PATH, I wrote: C:\Windows\

but it should have been:
C:\Windows\System32

now I have no errors anymore, case closed!

Answer (score 0):

1. Change flutter path to > C:\yourUsername\flutter\bin
2. Add this path > C:\Windows\system32

Make these changes in System Variables