# VSCode: Quickly switch between flutter versions

Tags: flutter

So, I’m using flutter version 2.2.3 and can’t upgrade right now. But, my other project need higher SDK. I know, there is FVM. But I found this: [How to use two version of flutter on same device for different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783494/how-to-use-two-version-of-flutter-on-same-device-for-different-projects) and cite the article: https://dartcode.org/docs/quickly-switching-between-sdk-versions/

The article said, we can quickly switch flutter version via clickable status bar after applied git worktree. But, in my VSCode, flutter version not clickable. [image]

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I’ve found the answer:

1. Open workspace setting with CMD + SHFT + P, I choose not JSON version
2. Search for “SDK”
3. Add item with both of flutter version (mine: /User/me/flutter and /User/me/flutter-master)
   [image]

And voila! I can choose other versions
[image]

Answer (score 3):

FVM is a good choice, but if you want to use built-in mechanism, you'll have to:

1. Download different Flutter versions (from [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases))
2. In VSCode set SDK paths (inside `.vscode/settings.json` file for single project or globally in settings):

```json
{
    "dart.sdkPaths": [
        "/Users/user/flutter/stable"
        "/Users/user/flutter/beta"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using vs code you can click `ctrl+shift+p` or `command+shift+p`
and search for "select SDK" and select your SDK.