# MacOS + VSCode multiple flutter versions

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to have multiple flutter versions in MacOS, namely 2.0.4 & 3.7.1.

I have seen topics like this one [VSCode: Quickly switch between flutter versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196386/vscode-quickly-switch-between-flutter-versions) and followed tutorials like this one https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-multiple-flutter-versions-on-macos-522x35ei but even after everything seems correctly defined, I'm stuck with the version 2.0.4, in the newest project.

**1 -** I have configured the `$PATH` permanently:

Old version 2.0.4

```
which flutter
/Users/MyUserName/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter
```

New version 3.7.1

```
which flutter371
/Users/MyUserName/Documents/flutter_3_7_1/bin/flutter371
```

**2 -** I have configured in VSCode the file /.vscode/settings.json like such:
[image]

**3 -** I have configured directly into VSCode settings the `Flutter SDK paths` like such:
[image]

Yet, when I click the in VSCode bottom navigation bar Flutter, it only shows this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that by renaming the executable to flutter371, VSCode does not recognize the path "/Users/MyUserName/Documents/flutter_3_7_1" as a valid SDK anymore?

Comment: Well, according to this tutorial https://hackernoon.com/how-to-run-multiple-flutter-versions-on-macos-522x35ei you can rename it as you wish, in that case, the person renamed it as `flutterstable`. But I'm gonna test `flutter` only.

Comment: Yeah, didn't get any luck. Still the same problem.

Comment: Show the JSON text of your settings instead of screenshots please. (see [ask] for why).

Answer (score 1):

> Could it be that by renaming the executable to flutter371

This is the problem. When VS Code searches for a Flutter SDK in the `dart.flutterSdkPaths`, it looks for a `bin/flutter` binary to ensure it's an SDK.

One way around this be to copy the file instead of renaming it, so it's still a valid Flutter SDK. You may need to ensure these folders are in the right order in your `PATH` environment variable if you want to mix it with another SDK though.