# How to use a different flutter version on a specific project

Tags: flutter

I have some of my flutter project that depends on `flutter 2.10` and I have some that depends on `flutter > 3.0`. So if I want to work on any of my project depending on `flutter > 3.0`, I have to run `flutter upgrade`, vice versa for running project depending on `flutter 2.10`, I have to run `flutter downgrade`.

Is there a better way for me to use different version for a specific project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use two version of flutter on same device for different projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783494/how-to-use-two-version-of-flutter-on-same-device-for-different-projects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the "flutter version management" for this: https://fvm.app.  That'll let you download nearly any previous and current flutter release, and associate them on a project-by-project basis.  It's quite robust and production-worthy.

Answer (score 0):

First the download the required flutter SDK.

If you are using Android Studio, you can change the Flutter version by navigating to **Android Studio -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Flutte**r. After changing the version, apply the settings and check the bottom section to confirm the current version.

For double confirmation, you can also go to Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Doctor, where you can see the Flutter version used by the project.
[image]